# How can I boot a MacBook Pro from a USB drive?

Tags: mac, usb, boot, macbook

I have a bootable USB drive.

Is it possible to boot a MacBook Pro from it, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Sure - restart your computer and hold down the <strike>command</strike> **option** key while it's booting. Eventually a few icons will pop up on the screen and you'll be able to choose which device you want to boot from.

Comment: Correction: it's the Option key you hold to get the startup manager.

Comment: Jeez - I should really know that since I use bootcamp at least a few times per month.

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea to change your answer accordingly ;)